# Android RecyclerView Adapter is giving null on unit testing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-junit

I am trying to test RecyclerView with AndroidJunit4, it is my test code:

```
package com.kaushik.myredmart.ui;
// all includes
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ProductListActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ProductListActivity> rule  = new  ActivityTestRule<>(ProductListActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void ensureListViewIsPresent() throws Exception {
        ProductListActivity activity = rule.getActivity();
        View viewByIdw = activity.findViewById(R.id.productListView);
        assertThat(viewByIdw,notNullValue());
        assertThat(viewByIdw, instanceOf(RecyclerView.class));
        RecyclerView productRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) viewByIdw;
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = productRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        assertThat(adapter, instanceOf(ProductAdapter.class));

    }
}
```

I am facing a problem to check the Adapter. Although productRecyclerView  is passing not null test and an instance of RecyclerView, it is following error in last line:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: an instance of com.kaushik.myredmart.adapter.ProductAdapter
but: null
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
at com.kaushik.myredmart.ui.ProductListActivityTest.ensureListViewIsPresent(ProductListActivityTest.java:45)
```

What is the problem in code?

Comment: Can you post your `ProductListActivity` code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging from this line:

> Expected: an instance of com.kaushik.myredmart.adapter.ProductAdapter
>   but: null

One can conclude, that this:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = productRecyclerView.getAdapter();
```

returns `null`, which may happen when there has not been performed `productRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Make sure you are correctly setting adapter in activity lifecycle callbacks (i.e. in `onCreate()`). It seems to me you are creating and setting adapter after some action/callback.